# How to get a "approximately follows distribution" symbol?

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

I want to create an "approximately follows distribution" symbol. It should be a `\sim` with one dot above and one below.

I have tried using `\underset` and `\overset`, but I cannot get the dots to be the same distance above and below `\sim`.

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Could you overlay a colon on `\sim` with some manual adjustment to get it at the right height?

Comment: Ah maybe. How do you do that?

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12895/overlay-symbol-with-another or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413333/overlay-symbols

Comment: there's also ⩫ (U+2A6B), but that might not be what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\approxsim{\mathpalette\@approxsim\relax}
\newcommand\@approxsim[2]{%
  \mathrel{%
    \ooalign{%
      $\m@th#1\sim$\cr
      \hidewidth$\m@th#1:$\hidewidth\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a \approxsim b_{a \approxsim b_{a \approxsim b}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is maybe a bit nicer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\approxsim{\mathchoice
  {\@approxsim {\displaystyle}      {1ex} }
  {\@approxsim {\textstyle}         {1ex} }
  {\@approxsim {\scriptstyle}       {.7ex}}
  {\@approxsim {\scriptscriptstyle} {.5ex}}}
\newcommand\@approxsim[2]{%
  \mathrel{%
    \ooalign{%
      $\m@th#1\sim$\cr
      \hidewidth$\m@th#1.$\hidewidth\cr
      \hidewidth\raise #2 \hbox{$\m@th#1.$}\hidewidth\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a \approxsim b_{a \approxsim b_{a \approxsim b}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this, although is there any way to get the top dot a little higher?

Comment: In the first version you could raise the colon a bit  by using `\mathop:`.

Answer (score 2):

## Symbol

The Unicode code point is probably U+2A6B (tilde operator with rising dots).

## LuaTeX/XeTeX

If LuaTeX or XeTeX is used, the symbol is available in Asana Math and XITS math.
Package `unicode-math` used the command sequence `\rsimdots`. Also, the character can be used directly or as `^`-escape: `^^^^2a6b`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
  \def\test#1{\fontspec{#1}^^^^2a6b&#1\\}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \test{Asana Math}
    \test{XITS Math}
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## pdfTeX

A "poor man's" symbol constructed from `\sim` and two `\cdot`s. The colon is not vertically centered, thus the position of the dots are not well defined.

See the code comments for the fine tuning:

- The distance from the dots can be configured in the setting of `\dimen@`.
- The rotation angle is given to `\rotatebox`. If rotation is not wanted, this line can be removed.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rsimdots}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\@rsimdots{}% Adopt to math style size via \mathpalette
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@rsimdots}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \sbox0{$#1\sim\m@th$}%
  \sbox2{$#1\vcenter{}$}% \ht2 is height of the math axis
  \dimen@=.75\ht2\relax % distance dot to math axis
  \sbox2{$#1\cdot\m@th$}% single vertically centered dot
  \sbox2{% two dots above and below the math axis
    \rlap{\raisebox{\dimen@}{\copy2}}%
    \raisebox{-\dimen@}{\copy2}%
  }%
  % Rotate the two dots.
  \sbox2{$#1\rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{\copy2}$}%
  % Combine symbol
  \rlap{\hbox to \wd0{\hss\copy2\hss}}%
  \copy0 %
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  A\rsimdots B,
  \scriptstyle A\rsimdots B,
  \scriptscriptstyle A\rsimdots B
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result pdfTeX]